# CoreData fetch out of order

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nsfetchrequest

This seems extremely trivial that I shouldn't have to ask but I haven't seen anything out there on it. If I save an array of objects (or "set") to CoreData why does it always return it out of order? There is no specific order to each array (user makes a list) so I don't believe there is any regex or sort descriptor that would work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To keep a user-defined ordering you can add an integer attribute (e.g. "sortOrder") to the corresponding entity in your data model. You can use this attribute to keep track of the sort ordering manually by updating the attribute in the managed object when the user changes the order in the list. You'll then be able to execute a fetch request and specify a sort descriptor based on the "sortOrder" attribute to get the results returned from the fetch in their original user-defined order.

If you are using iOS 5 or 10.7+ you could create your model in such a way that you have an ordered to-many relationship.  See the [iOS 5.0 / OS X 10.7 release notes](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/DataManagement/RN-CoreData/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010637-CH1-DontLinkElementID_3). In Interface Builder, select the relevant relationship and check the "ordered" checkbox.

Comment: Why bother with a `sortOrder` property and just sort however you need to when executing a fetch request?

Comment: The original poster said that there is no order to the data (e.g. it's not chronological, it's not alphabetical, etc.) because the user defines the order of the list as they add and rearrange items. Adding a sortOrder property allows the order to be persisted in the model, which is then kept up to date as the user manipulates the order through the table view or otherwise. The sortOrder property can then be used in an NSSortDescriptor to sort the items in the same order that the user had previously set.

Comment: @Andrew thank you for your help. I was hoping that I wouldn't have to resort to adding sort attributes to all my db entities but I guess it's the only way :(

Comment: @random i've updated my answer to include a second method, though you do take a performance hit if you are storing a lot of data.

Comment: @Andrew Thank you again for your help. Unfortunately I am storing a lot of data...a whole whole lot of data so it looks like the first method will work best.

Answer (score 2):

`NSSet` has no guaranteed order.  You need an `NSArray` to be able to find a specific element or control the order of the return set.

Comment: It is very clear in the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html). Sort descriptors are very common in this scenario.

Comment: It is noted in the docs but there is no descriptor to sort by is the issue. Andrew's answer is what I am going with.

Answer (score 1):

Because an `NSSet` *is* an unordered collection.  You can apply any sort descriptor via `sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:` to your `NSSet`, which will return an `NSArray` of ordered results.

Reference Apple's documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html